# Cookies not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

When a new user visits my site I want to redirect them to /welcome but only once, I thought to do this I could use cookies and set a cookie forever once they had visited the welcome page and then checking if the cookie existed before sending them to /welcome.

Here I have a base controller

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->checkWelcome($request);
    }

    private function checkWelcome(Request $request) {
        $currentRoute = Route::currentRouteName();

        if ($currentRoute != 'frontend.guest.welcome' && Cookie::get('visited_welcome') != '1') {
            header('location: ' . route('frontend.guest.welcome'));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

When sending to `frontend.guest.welcome` it has a route to WelcomeController

```
Route::get('/welcome', ['uses' => 'WelcomeController@getView', 'as' => 'frontend.guest.welcome']);
```

Here is WelcomeController

```
class WelcomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function getView()
    {
        Cookie::forever('visited_welcome', '1');

        return view('frontend.guest.welcome');
    }
}
```

The issue is, its constantly sending to /welcome, not once but always.

Answer (score 5):

try to except your cookie in app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php

```
class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'visited_welcome'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't returning the cookie with the response, attach it to the response like so:

```
public function checkWelcome(Request $request) {
{
    if (!$request->cookie('visited_welcome')) {
        return redirect('frontend.guest.welcome')->withCookie(Cookie::forever('visited_welcome', '1'));
    }

    // otherwise proceed as normal
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `queue` method on the Cookie facade:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('visited_welcome', '1'));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses

A better approach may be using middleware, that way you wouldn't need to implement any check in your controller code. For example:

```
// CheckIfFirstTimeVisit.php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->cookies->has('visited_welcome')) {
        return $request($next);
    }

    return response()->view('frontend.guest.welcome')
                     ->withCookie(Cookie::forever('visited_welcome', '1'));
}
```

Comment: ILU. Was fighting with this for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CookieController extends Controller {

   /* below code a set a cookie in browser */
   public function setCookie(Request $request){
      $response = new Response('Hello World');
      $response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'Anything else'));
      return $response;
   }
   /* below code a get a cookie in browser */
   public function getCookie(Request $request){
      $value = $request->cookie('name');
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30164659)